# RecyclerView losing Checkbox status despite storing it

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've read that you have to store the item's state and set it again because it gets cleared from the RAM. For me, If I keep scrolling up and down in a bit longer list (10-15 item) random checks will appear and disappear. Below is how I store it and set it. What should I set apart from these? I'm using this inside a fragment.

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BettingViewHolder holder, int position) {
    BettingItem item = items.get(position);
    holder.homeTextView.setText(item.homeTeam);
    holder.awayTextView.setText(item.awayTeam);
    holder.dateTextView.setText(item.date);
    holder.leagueTextView.setText(item.league);
    holder.sportsTextView.setText(item.sport);
    holder.homeOddsTextView.setText(Double.toString(item.homeOdds));
    holder.drawOddsTextView.setText(Double.toString(item.drawOdds));
    holder.awayOddsTextView.setText(Double.toString(item.awayOdds));

    switch (item.outcome) {
        case HOME:
            holder.homeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case DRAW:
            holder.drawCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case AWAY:
            holder.awayCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            break;

        default:
            holder.homeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            holder.drawCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            holder.awayCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            break;
    }

    holder.item = item;
}




//its a part from ViewHolder's constructor
homeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
    if (item != null) {
        homeCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            item.outcome = BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("HOME");
            drawCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            awayCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            if (item.outcome == BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("HOME"))
                item.outcome = BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("NONE");
        }

        listener.onEventSelected(item);
    }
}
});

drawCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
    if (item != null) {
        drawCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);

        if (isChecked) {
            item.outcome = BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("DRAW");
            homeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            awayCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            if (item.outcome == BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("DRAW"))
                item.outcome = BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("NONE");
        }
        listener.onEventSelected(item);
    }
}
});

awayCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
    if (item != null) {
        awayCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            item.outcome = BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("AWAY");
            drawCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            homeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            if (item.outcome == BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("AWAY"))
                item.outcome = BettingItem.Outcome.valueOf("NONE");
        }

        listener.onEventSelected(item);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to uncheck the old checkboxes, because the viewHolders got recycled (if the old checkBoxes were selected, it'll remain selected).

```java
switch (item.outcome) {
    case HOME:
        holder.homeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        holder.drawCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.awayCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        break;

    case DRAW:
        holder.homeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.drawCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        holder.awayCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        break;

    case AWAY:
        holder.homeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.drawCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.awayCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        break;

    default:
        holder.homeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.drawCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.awayCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        break;
}
```

> I would only want this behaviour if the user taps on it. I don't know
>   yet how to seperate these.

in this case, do something like this in your onCheckedChangedListener

```
homeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(buttonView, isChecked -> {
    if(buttonView.isPressed()){
       //user pressed the button. (handle user clicks)
    } else {
       //the program toggled the checkbox (do nothing)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out the other problem based on your answer: when the RecyclerView gets destroyed, it also calls the CheckBoxChanged listener, which will turn the outcome to NONE. I would only want this behaviour if the user taps on it. I don't know yet how to seperate these.

Comment: @Dinter, look at the edits, to only handle user selections.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically create list of objects to store your checkbox status with default status (you can use Boolean) and you need to set your recycler view checkbox status from that list. By the way, your status list need to have same size as your total cell size to avoid index out of range error. Also, when your status change you need to change your list of object in your already created list.